# Adding Task to Tasklist in ForLoop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I need to send a request to multiple servers and am trying to use tasks to run each connection asynchronously.  I have a function that is configured to make the connections:

```
 internal static Task<EventRecordEx> GetEventRecordFromServer(string server, string activityID)
```

I have tried the following but it runs synchronously...

```
var taskList = new List<Task<EventRecordEx>>();
foreach (string server in server_list)
{
    taskList.Add(GetEventRecordFromServer(server, id));
}
await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList.ToArray(), completedTasks =>
{
    foreach (var task in completedTasks)
    {  
        // do something with the results
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The server calls are running async. You are waiting `async` for all of your calls to finish before it can continue. This code is fine.

Comment: You should be using `await Task.WhenAll(taskList)` instead of `Task.Facture.ContinueWhenAll`

Comment: @JohanP - Seemed like the logging showed the same thread for all of the server calls...  I removed the Task<EventRecoredEx> from the function and used taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetEventRecordFromServer(server, id))); and each call seemed to run under a different thread...

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding when you use .ContinueWhenAll, you'll have a hard time debugging for the exceptions when one of the tasks fail as it will return an AggregateException, I'd suggest running the task individually, then use .ConfigureAwait(false) to make sure that it runs in a nun UI thread like so:

```
foreach(Task task in taskList.ToArray()){

    await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Do something.
}
```